# Jquery: How to test multiple values of a dropdown

Tags: jquery

I am using the selection of an item in a dropdown box to hide and show a div.
I am new to jquery. I want to be able to test for multiple values such that If
p1,p2 and p3 are selected the div with id specify-source will show. So far it works for p1 now. How can I write this for multiple values?

```
<select name = "genericId" id="myselect" >
<option value="p1">Section1</option>
<option value="p2">Section2</option> 
<option value="p3">Section3</option>
<option value="j2">Section4</option> 
<option value="j3">Section5</option>
</select>

 <div id="specify-source">
    <p class="headerSection">Select Branch</p>
    <select name="listOfBranches" id="brnlist">
        <option value="0">Branch 1</option>
        <option value="1">Branch 2</option>
        <option value="2">Branch 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This works.

```
  $('#myselect').change(function () {
        ($(this).val() == "p1") ? $('#specify-source').show() : $('#specify-source').hide();
    });
```

I will like to test for  multiple values like p1,p2,p3

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the condition to your if statement using the OR operator `||`

```
$('#myselect').change(function () {
  if($(this).val() == "p1" || $(this).val() == "p2" || $(this).val() == "p3"){
     $('#specify-source').show()
  }else
  { 
     $('#specify-source').hide();
  }
});
```

In order to make it for 7 comparisons, let's use a switch statement:

```
$('#myselect').change(function () {
  var target = $(this).val();
  switch (target)
   {
    case "p1":
    case "p2":
    case "p3":
     $('#specify-source').show()
    break;
    case "p4":
    //your p4 code
    break;
    default:
    //default code to execute
     $('#specify-source').hide();
   }
});
```

When the action to be executed is similar put the conditions after each other without using `break;`.

Comment: I plan to make about 7 comparisons and on the 4th comparison p4 Jquery seems to be complaining. Maybe there is a limit to the number of variables you can compare. How do I handle for 7 comparisons?

Comment: @user2320476 A switch statement is the way to go, give me 5 min i ll type it up.

Answer (score 0):

From Jquery documentation

> In the case of `<select multiple="multiple">` elements, the .val()
>   method returns an array containing each selected option

http://api.jquery.com/val/

You may loop the array to see if any of them are present.